# After modifying express.js res.send function it won't emit any data

Tags: node.js, express

Basically what I'm trying to do is unify every response of my application just so they look like this

```
{
  success: true,
  error: "Error description",
  errorCode: "SomeError",
  data: {
    ...
  }
}
```

Copying and pasting this structure everywhere as well as wrapper function looks quite ugly to me, so I've tried to modify `send` function so that it accepts 4 params instead of only 1 and then makes given structure.

I've found various examples on how to modify `send` function and came up with this middleware

```
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  const oldSend = res.send;

  res.send = function (data = {}, success = true, error = '', errorCode = '') {
    let response = {
      data,
      success,
      error,
      errorCode
    };

    oldSend.apply(res, response);
  };

  next();
});
```

so the res.send call looks like this

```
res.json(req.session.key != null, true, null, null);
```

Which works fine except it doesn't return any response to the client. Could you help me solve this? Is it possible to achieve expected behaviour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `function.apply` which expects a `this` and then *an array of the function arguments* (see [MDN for function.prototype.apply](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply)).  What you need to use instead is `function.call` (again see [MDN for function.prototype.call](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call)).

However, a word of caution to be careful of overwriting a low level part of express (or any library) - you don't know what else might be calling this so you may get some unexpected results.  You might like to check (for example) that the supplied parameter is of a type which you expect (e.g. an object) and pass anything unexpected (e.g. a `Buffer`) straight through to the original send.

Comment: Thanks for the correction, but I've already tried using `call` instead. Unfortunately it creates infinite loop of `send` calls somehow. Edited my question

Comment: @AndreyInihov You don't normally edit the question making a given answer invalid.  It would have been good to indicate originally that you had tried call and this resulted in an infinite loop.  Given that I would suggest NOT overwriting a low level function - clearly it is calling itself after some transformation of the data, which is entirely up to express how they want to implement that.  Instead, it would be much safer to extend with your own send function.

Comment: My bad. Reverted so that your answer is still valid. Seems like infinite loop is created by data transformation: if I stringify resulting object everything goes well. Probably I'll leave it so with type checking

Comment: Still, be careful.  If the express.js team decide to change how they do things later, your code may break.  Overriding bits of libraries is always risky.